# Solution to $y'=\frac{(x+y)^2}{(x+2)(y-2)}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

$$y'=\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{(x+y)^2}{(x+2)(y-2)}$$ According to me it is not a homogenous equation as the degree of the terms is different. I even tried reducing it to some of the standard forms, but I haven´t managed it.

Comment: Is the edit right ?

Comment: If I write $x+y=x+2+y-2$ would it be enough to continue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*A.G.*'s comment is equivalent to performing a translation to make the constants in the expression zero. The translation does not change the gradient, so we just need to solve $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{(x+y)^2}{xy}$ and then undo the translation.

Comment: I didn't get u user21820

Comment: @ATREYADANTURTI: Which part do you not get? Do you know what a translation is?

Comment: Nope what is it

Comment: @ATREYADANTURTI: Try Google or Wikipedia when you meet a term you don't understand. I'll give you the link this time: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_%28mathematics%29.

Comment: @ATREYADANTURTI: So my answer says: "Shift the graph around such that the equation for the gradient of the shifted graph has no more "$2$" in it but becomes $\frac{(x+y)^2}{xy}$. Then you can solve the equation because it is now homogenous. Then you undo the shifting to figure out the original graph."

Comment: Wonderful thx bro !

Comment: @ATREYADANTURTI: You're welcome!

Comment: Just call me atreya

Comment: @ATREYADANTURTI: If we put `@<username>` anywhere in the comment that user will be notified of the message. You could always change your username under your profile (click on your score/badges at the top to get there).

Comment: No probLm and thx